# Translating C# into F# Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, f#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a Tinder interface in my iOS F# app. To do so, I am using the xCardView component available here: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/XCardView/true

I am now translating the following `C#` class in `F#`:

```
    using Softweb.Xamarin.Controls.iOS;

public class DemoViewController : UIViewController, ICardViewDataSource
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

    //Returns a random byte
    private Func<byte> r = () => (Guid.NewGuid()).ToByteArray() [random.Next(0, 15)];

    public CardView DemoCardView { get; set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        DemoCardView = new CardView();

        //Wire up events
        DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft += OnSwipe;
        DemoCardView.DidSwipeRight += OnSwipe;
        DemoCardView.DidCancelSwipe += OnSwipeCancelled;
        DemoCardView.DidStartSwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwipeStarted;
        DemoCardView.SwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwiping;
        DemoCardView.DidEndSwipingCard += OnSwipeEnded;
    }

    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        DemoCardView.Center = new CGPoint (View.Center.X, View.Center.Y - 10f);
        DemoCardView.Bounds = new CGRect (0f, 0f, View.Bounds.Width - 20f, View.Bounds.Height - 100f);
        View.AddSubview(DemoCardView);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
        DemoCardView.DataSource = this;
    }

    public UIView NextCardForCardView(CardView cardView)
    {
        //Create a card with a random background color
        var card = new UIView {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(r(), r(), r()),
            Frame = DemoCardView.Bounds
        };

        //Rasterize card for more efficient animation
        card.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;

        return card;
    }   

    void OnSwipe(object sender, SwipeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("View swiped.\n");
    }

    void OnSwipeCancelled(object sender, SwipeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Swipe cancelled.\n");
    }

    void OnSwipeStarted(object sender, SwipingStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Started swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }

    void OnSwiping(object sender, SwipingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }

    void OnSwipeEnded(object sender, SwipingEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Ended swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }
}
```

To do so I have done the following:

```
namespace Dissertation

open System

open Foundation
open Foundation
open UIKit
open CoreGraphics
open Softweb.Xamarin.Controls.iOS

[<Register ("BackgroundAnimationViewController")>]
type BackgroundAnimationViewController (handle:IntPtr) =
    inherit UIViewController (handle)



    let demoCardView = new CardView()

    let onSwipe(sender : Object, e : SwipeEventArgs) = 
        Console.WriteLine("Swiped")

    override x.DidReceiveMemoryWarning () =
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.

    override x.ViewWillLayoutSubviews() = 
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        demoCardView.Center <- new CGPoint(x.View.Center.X, x.View.Center.Y - Conversions.nfloat(10))
        demoCardView.Bounds <- new CGRect(Conversions.nfloat(0), Conversions.nfloat(0), x.View.Bounds.Width - Conversions.nfloat(20), x.View.Bounds.Height - Conversions.nfloat(100))
        x.View.AddSubview(demoCardView)

    override x.ViewDidLayoutSubviews() = 
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        demoCardView.DataSource <- x



    override x.ViewDidLoad () =
        base.ViewDidLoad ()
        x.View.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.White





               ////Wire up events
               //DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft += OnSwipe;
               //DemoCardView.DidSwipeRight += OnSwipe;
               //DemoCardView.DidCancelSwipe += OnSwipeCancelled;
               //DemoCardView.DidStartSwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwipeStarted;
               //DemoCardView.SwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwiping;
               //DemoCardView.DidEndSwipingCard += OnSwipeEnded;






    override x.ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (toInterfaceOrientation) =
        // Return true for supported orientations
        if UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone then
           toInterfaceOrientation <> UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
        else
           true

    interface ICardViewDataSource with 
         member this.NextCardForCardView(cardView : CardView) = 
            let card = new UIView()
            card.Frame <- demoCardView.Bounds
            card.Layer.RasterizationScale <- UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale
            card.Layer.ShouldRasterize <- true
            Console.WriteLine("Returning card")
            card 

         member this.get_Handle() = 
             new nativeint()

         member this.Dispose() = 
             Console.WriteLine("Disposed")
```

I am facing the following issues:

1. The `ICardViewDataSource` seems to not be implemented correctly, as I do not see any cards on the screen and the `Returning card` text never appears in the console.
2. I am not sure what the `+=` operator is in `C#` and how to translate it into `F#` or what signatures to provide for the `onSwipe`, `onSwipeCancelled` etc. functions.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer since I don't know Xamarin.iOS well enough, but from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/events it looks like you'd use `DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft.Add(onSwipe)` to add your event handler. It also looks like the `Add(handler)` method can take functions of either one or two tupled parameters: either a single parameter that's just an `EventArgs` (or a class derived from `EventArgs`), or else a 2-tuple parameter of `(sender : Object, e : EventArgs)`. In other words, your `onSwipe` method looks like it has the right signature.